# Flutter Fixed Button in CustomScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-sliver

How to make a button Fixed "Sticky" in bottom of CustomScrollView

How to achieve like the screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDCn9.png

Comment: you can use a Stack() with a positioned widget.

Comment: Have you tried anything at least? What about Containers and Columns and Align widgets? https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041

Comment: As my question indicate 'CustomScrollView' so only slivers are accepted inside CustomScrollView and not what you've mentioned

Answer (score 68, accepted):

One Way of Doing it - using - `BottomNavigationBar`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>\[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Sliver App Bar'),
            expandedHeight: 125.0,
          ),
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, int) {
            return Text('Boo');
          }, childCount: 65)),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Text('Foo Text'),
          ),
        \],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text('Fixed Button'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }][1]][1]
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: How can I push the fixed button up if keyboard shows?

Comment: Even though this is a pure "hack", it works perfectly with CustomScrollView, it persists when the user scrolls.

Comment: @WaleedAlrashed I know this is an old answer, but why would this be considered a "hack"? What are the normal use cases of BottomNavigationBar besides buttons for navigation?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `floatingActionButton` and `floatingActionButtonLocation`

exam:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {},
          isExtended: true,
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
          label: Text('Fixed Button'),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            const SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 250.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text('Demo'),
              ),
            ),
            SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                childAspectRatio: 4.0,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                    child: Text('grid item $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
            SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 50.0,
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                    child: Text('list item $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
      body: 
      // list view here
      bottomNavigationBar: GestureDetector(
  child: Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 325,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "title",
      ),
    onTap: (){},
  ),
);
```

this works for me as a work around

Comment: I am against this work around, there are a lot of alternatives, like a floating button or widget, and here you are using a scaffold attribute that is supposed to serve another purpose.

Comment: Use the bottomNavigationBar just like a floating action button. And Scaffold is used for every screen

Comment: The Scaffold has a floatingActionButton property, if you want to use it as a father widget than that's the way to go https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html

Comment: it is better solution than using floatingactionbutton.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap up your scrollable widget with a Expanded widget. It will take up required space and leave the remaining for your button. Here's how i used to make the button stick both top & bottom.

```
Column(
            children: [
              //This is button 1
              Padding(
                padding: allPadding,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const myPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Button Name",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
              //Here's my Scrollable widget
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: provider.myList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      return myCard(
                        provider: provider,
                        widgetTextStyle: widgetTextStyle,
                        index: index,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),


             //this is the same button used as above
              Padding(
                padding: allPadding,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const myPage2(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Button 2",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```